# How to reject requests from a bot with Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have recently made a site with Flask and have published it with pythonanywhere succesfully. However, I keep getting requests from bots using weird url's. They are clearly trying to access common wordpress pages as all the url's have "wp-" in the string.

I am trying to find a way to block these requests completely so as not to waste computer space. I have been able to find a way to not respond with pages, but I still receive GET requests. Is there any way to not even receieve GET requests if it contains certain text in the url.

What I have tried so far is :

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():

    if "wp-" in request.path:
        print("BOT INTRUDER!!")
        return Response(status=204)
```

My site doesn't react to requests with "wp-" in the url now but looking at the access log, I still receive GET requests

Answer (score 0):

Those requests will always appear in you access log. They are still requests that were handled by you web app.

Comment: is there anyway I can stop my app from "handling" them?

Comment: No, there is not

Answer (score 0):

My two cents in the matter:
Someone will have to handle it. If you want your app server to be saved from unwarranted requests, you can consider some third-party solutions like Cloudfare.
Or dedicate a myriad of servers with sufficient bandwidth to filter traffic for your app server (Impractical as it seems.)